# Show the rss description element on another page - php

Tags: php, parsing, rss

I am parsing rss feed using a small program i have written. I want the user to see a small exerpt of the rss description element on the first page which i have done as below:

```
   $rss = new DOMDocument();
                    $rss->load($rsslink);
                    $feed = array();
                    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
                        $item = array ( 
                            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                            'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
                            'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,

                        );
                       array_push($feed, $item);
                    }

                    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
                        $randomnum= rand(5, 20);
                        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
                        $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
                        $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
                        $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
                        echo '<b>'.$title.'</b><br />';
                        echo '<i>Posted on '.$date.'</i><br/><br/>';

                          $des = strip_tags($description);

                       echo $this-> get_words_until($des,70);
                       echo '<a href="">readmore</a>';

                        echo '<br/>';
                    }
```

**1.**

[image]

**2.**

[image]

I want to achieve something like the second image on another php page when the user clicks on the **read more link**

Please can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you understand what you are doing with `get_words_until` method?